# How to run a command in sed in Linux?

Tags: linux, sed

```
sed -i 's/1.1.1.1/ `hostname -I | cut -f1 -d " "`/g' file.txt
```

Not able to overwrite IP address using sed command in a given file. How to run this (`hostname -I | cut -f1 -d " "`) command with sed command?

Comment: Double quotes instead of single should work.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/1\.1\.1\.1/{s//$(hostname -I | cut -f1 -d " ")/;s/.*/echo "&"/e}' file
```

Place the commands between `$(...)` and then echo the line using the evaluate flag of the substitution command.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a variable.

```
hn=$(hostname -I | cut -f1 -d" ") && sed -i "s/1\.1\.1\.1/$hn/g" file
```

Sed's `e` and `s///e` work on the entire pattern space, so it's just more trouble than it's worth.